# dd/mm/yyyy format, but how about d/m/yyyy format to Ymd

Tags: php, time

how can we format

```
12/4/2012 to 20120412
```

and

```
4/11/2012 to 20121104
```

or

```
5/4/2012 to 20120405
```

using php?

i have use `strtotime()` and

```
$date = new DateTime('4/11/2012');
$date = $date->format('Ymd');
```

but they all fail, **is there a function in php that solve this**? or we have to use something like regex?

Comment: 2012114 ? Why in Cthulu's name would you want that? 20121104

Comment: @TonyHopkinson HAHAH edited/ sorry

Comment: Thank the tentacled one for that, thought I'd logged in to InsaneAssylumOverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation to `strtotime()`, you'll see that it makes assumptions about whether a date is in `dd mm yyyy` or `mm dd yyyy` format.

In short, the assumption changes depending on whether the string contains hyphens or slashes as the separators. Unfortunately, both hyphens and slashes are used by people writing both formats, so there are always going to be examples that are misinterpreted by `strtotime()`.

Because of this, neither format is ideal, because of the ambiguity between the two of them. The best option is to provide the date to the program in a less ambiguous format.

You could do a string replace on the input string to set the separators to the expected format before you call `strtotime()`. Not a great solution, but it does work.

If you can't change the input format, and if you know for certain which format you'll be receiving, you can use the [`DateTime::createFromFormat`] method instead of `strtotime()`. This parses date strings as  `strtotime()` does, but takes a specific format string, so you can tell it exactly what you're expecting, so removes the ambiguity.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this work great! `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '5/4/2012');$date = $date->format('Ymd');`

Comment: anyway what is a title that can easy found by people who are searching this, there is no question yet i search is asking about `how to make 01/08/2012 1/08/2012 = same` either way, i don't know the good title. for this problem. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function x($string) {
    $array = explode('/', $string);
    $a = $array[0];
    $b = $array[1];
    $c = $array[2];
    if (( (int)$a - 10) < 0) { $a = "0$a"; }
    if (( (int)$b - 10) < 0) { $b = "0$a"; }
    return "{$c}{$b}{$a}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your date examples are ambiguous, and could be either `DMY` or `MDY` dates. You will need to parse the date yourself, something along the lines of

```
list($d, $m, $y) = explode('/', $date);
// compose your output from $d, $m and $y
```

Comment: how do you add 0 if its 1 numeric?

Comment: Consider [formatting your string](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateTime = strtotime('12/4/2012');
$output   = date('Ymd',$dateTime);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: it fails. thats why im posting this

Comment: `strtotime()` gives precedence to `MDY` dates over `DMY` dates.

Comment: @AdamRamadhan, it shouldn't. Whay is the output with the above code?

Comment: Exactly, I've been doing this for ages!

Comment: @jeffrey for the sake of consistency, like 1/2/2012 to 01/02/2012

Comment: I'm still confused why this "fails."